# How to Mock a class in Scala

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, jmockit

I am using Scala 2.11. can I use Scala test or Mockito to mock Scala Classes? All the examples that I see on StackOverflow and other blogs are mocking scala Traits rather than classes. Also  I tried to use JMockit and it does not seem to work with Scala.

Comment: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using scalatest and the provided `MockitoSugar` module, you can do something like this (take from the [official scalatest user guide](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects#mockito))

```
// First, create the mock object
val mockCollaborator = mock[Collaborator]
// Create the class under test and pass the mock to it
classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest
classUnderTest.addListener(mockCollaborator)

// Use the class under test
classUnderTest.addDocument("Document", new Array[Byte](0))
classUnderTest.addDocument("Document", new Array[Byte](0))
classUnderTest.addDocument("Document", new Array[Byte](0))
classUnderTest.addDocument("Document", new Array[Byte](0))

// Then verify the class under test used the mock object as expected
verify(mockCollaborator).documentAdded("Document")
verify(mockCollaborator, times(3)).documentChanged("Document")
```

Comment: I saw that example, but what do we mean by Collaborator in this example? Is it the test class ?

Also is this line a valid scala syntax ? 
classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest

Comment: `Collaborator` is the class to be mocked.

Comment: what is `ClassUnderTest` in that case

Comment: The class you're testing. Mocks are generally used to test a specific class mocking its dependencies. In this case `ClassUnderTest` depends on `Collaborator`, which is being mocked.

Comment: So does my ClassUnderTest need to implement `addToListener` function?

Comment: no, that's specific for the class you're testing. `addToListener` is only an example of a method for which you're mocking the argument.

Comment: Mockito has limited use in scala because you cant use it to mock objects so you have to factor out the functionality in your objects into abstract classes which you can mock, spy, and test :-(